# Combinatoric's Division Rule

Tags: combinatorics

Which statement is correct?

Book(Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics) Definition :- There are **n/d** ways to do a task if it can be done using a procedure that can be carried out in **n** ways, **and for every way w, exactly d of the n ways correspond to way w.**
[image]

I think this statement is more accurate :- There are **n/d** ways to do a task if it can be done using a procedure that can be carried out in **n** ways, **and exactly every **d** of the **n** ways corresponds to the same sequence.**

*P.S. - I have written the part in Bold (where I have doubt). Sorry for my bad English (English is not my native language)*

Answer (score 1):

Well, your wording can use a little more polish, but do you seem to grasp the idea.

The requirement is that **every** way among the $n$ belongs to an *equivalence* class of exactly $d$ corresponding ways.

That is, you can *partition* the $n$ ways into *disjoint* sets of corresponding ways, each of which contains exactly $d$ ways (so every way is in exactly one of these, with no remainders).

And such.